# Is my php regular expression right?

Tags: php, regex

I am not good at regular expression. How to do a php regular expression, make a judge if a string first word is `(a-h)`, second word is `@`, third part are numbers(length range from 4-15)?

Is my php regular expression right?

```
$title  =  'c@356920'; //h@907659042423
if (preg_match ("/^[a-h]{1}\@[0-9]{4,15}/i", $title)) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Assuming you mean `letter` and not `word`, that looks OK to me, although the `\@` should just be `@` and `{1}` is superfluous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is all you need to match, you need to add the rear anchor sign, (`$`). So you need to change your code from that to this:

```
$title  =  'c@356920'; //h@907659042423
if (preg_match ("/^[a-h]{1}@[0-9]{4,15}$/i", $title)) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

You also do not need to escape the `@` symbol. Your regex, as is, will match any string which starts with that sequence, but allows for any other amount of data to follow afterwards (from the question I can't tell if that is something you are after or not).

Comment: @Matmarbon: I think it might be a good idea to leave it there should there need to change it, but if there will be no more changes, then yes I do agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good so far, but two minor changes

```
/^[a-h]{1}@[0-9]{4,15}$/i
```

- Don't escape `@`
- `$` at the end, because else you allow an arbitrary number of arbitrary characters after that (it's the "line end"-anchor).

Comment: True, but I want my 3 bytes of disk space back! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If we're playing golf here, I'd suggest this:

```
/^[a-h]@\d{4,15}$/i
```

(removed {1} and replaced [0-9] with \d)